# Assigning UIButton to UIView in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

In my project i used the below code for a purpose and it is working properly.
My code:

```
 UIView *view = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg",index]]] autorelease];

view.frame = CGRectMake(70, 80, 180, 260);
return view;
```

But here instead of UIImageView i would like to use UIButton,So I replaced the first lin eof above code by:

```
  UIView *view=[[UIButton alloc] setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)[scrollImages objectAtIndex:index] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But at this point i am getting an error message as

> "Initializing 'UIView*_strong' with an expression of incompatible type 'void'".

Can anyone help me to solve this by replacing UIImageView with UIButton....

Comment: why you want to change UIButton as UIview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `init` the instance of `UIButton` after created it via `alloc'

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[button setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)[scrollImages objectAtIndex:index] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIView *view = button;
```

`You must use an init... method to complete the initialization process`

`- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state` return nothing (void), it's certainly incompatible type with UIView.

Answer (score 0):

Like this...

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(pressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg",index]];
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(70, 80, 180, 260);
[self.view addSubview:button];
```